# Use XSLT to add key to all child nodes in XML to MS Access transfer

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I'm trying to use XSLT to add a key to all child nodes so tables created during an XML import into MS Access have a an appropriate identifier across all created tables.  I've used some examples I've found to cobble some XSLT together but I don't fundamentally understand how this works to the degree where I can troubleshoot it. I can get `Id` placeholder in the `Add` node, but the value is blank.  Is there a way to programmatically add the `Id` key to all child nodes without coding each one individually?  If not, how to I go about editing the XSLT to ensure the `Id` field comes through?

To complicate things, the `Add` element is always under `ContactDetails` but `ContactDetails` varies in terms of nodes relative to the `Id` element.   It may be 4-7 nodes deep, for example.

Sample XML:

```
<Response>


<Alices>
    <Alice>
        <Id>12345</Id>
        <Bobbers>
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
            <Bobs>
                <Bob>
                    <Organization>
                        <Name>John Doe</Name>
                        <ABB>987654</ABB>
                        <ContactDetails>
                            <Adds>
                                <Add>
                                    <Type>Postal</Type>
                                    <Line1>PO BOX 12345</Line1>
                                    <Suburb>Doeville</Suburb>
                                    <State>ENE</State>
                                    <PostCode>1111</PostCode>
                                    <Country>GB</Country>
                                    <Preferred>false</Preferred>
                                </Add>
                                <Add>
                                    <Type>Street</Type>
                                    <Line1>123 Anywhere</Line1>
                                    <Suburb>Doeville</Suburb>
                                    <State>ENE</State>
                                    <PostCode>1111</PostCode>
                                    <Country>GB</Country>
                                    <Preferred>true</Preferred>
                                </Add>
                            </Adds>
                            <PNs>
                                <PN>
                                    <Type>Mobile</Type>
                                    <Number>11111111</Number>
                                    <Preferred>true</Preferred>
                                </PN>
                            </PNS>
                            <EMs>
                                <EM>
                                    <Type>Personal</Type>
                                    <Add>j.doe@anywhere.com</Add>
                                    <Preferred>false</Preferred>
                                </EM>
                            </EMs>
                            <PreferredContactMethod>Email</PreferredContactMethod>
                        </ContactDetails>
                        <Contacts>
                            <Contact>
                                <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                                <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                            </Contact>
                        </Contacts>
                    </Organization>
                </Bob>
            </Bobs>
        </Bobbers>
        <Jons>
            <Jon>
                <Id>012991</Id>
                <PrimaryJon>true</PrimaryJon>
                <StartDate>1900-01-01</StartDate>
            </Jon>
        </Jons>
    </Alice>
</Alices>

</Response>
```

And the XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <dataroot>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </dataroot>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Adds">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Add">
        <Add>
            <Id><xsl:value-of select="../../Id"/></Id>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Add>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is what I'm after:

```
<Response>

<Alices>
    <Alice>
        <Id>12345</Id>
        <Bobbers>
            <Name>John Doe</Name>
            <Bobs>
                <Bob>
                    <Organization>
                        <Id>12345</Id>
                        <Name>John Doe</Name>
                        <ABB>987654</ABB>
                        <ContactDetails>
                            <Adds>
                                <Add>
                                    <Id>12345</Id>
                                    <Type>Postal</Type>
                                    <Line1>PO BOX 12345</Line1>
                                    <Suburb>Doeville</Suburb>
                                    <State>ENE</State>
                                    <PostCode>1111</PostCode>
                                    <Country>GB</Country>
                                    <Preferred>false</Preferred>
                                </Add>
                                <Add>
                                    <Id>12345</Id>                              
                                    <Type>Street</Type>
                                    <Line1>123 Anywhere</Line1>
                                    <Suburb>Doeville</Suburb>
                                    <State>ENE</State>
                                    <PostCode>1111</PostCode>
                                    <Country>GB</Country>
                                    <Preferred>true</Preferred>
                                </Add>
                            </Adds>
                            <PNs>
                                <PN>
                                    <Id>12345</Id>                              
                                    <Type>Mobile</Type>
                                    <Number>11111111</Number>
                                    <Preferred>true</Preferred>
                                </PN>
                            </PNS>
                            <EMs>
                                <EM>
                                    <Id>12345</Id>                              
                                    <Type>Personal</Type>
                                    <Add>j.doe@anywhere.com</Add>
                                    <Preferred>false</Preferred>
                                </EM>
                            </EMs>
                            <PreferredContactMethod>Email</PreferredContactMethod>
                        </ContactDetails>
                        <Contacts>
                            <Contact>
                                <Id>12345</Id>                          
                                <LastName>Doe</LastName>
                                <FirstName>John</FirstName>
                            </Contact>
                        </Contacts>
                    </Organization>
                </Bob>
            </Bobs>
        </Bobbers>
        <Jons>
            <Jon>
                <Id>012991</Id>
                <PrimaryJon>true</PrimaryJon>
                <StartDate>1900-01-01</StartDate>
            </Jon>
        </Jons>
    </Alice>
</Alices>

</Response>
```

Comment: `..` selects the parent element, `../..` the grandparent, that way `../../Id` selects the `Id` child element of the grandparent. For the `Add` element the grandparent is a `ContactDetails` element which doesn't have any `Id` child. It is not clear why you expect that to give anything but an empty value.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k added, thank you.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That is helpful, thank you.

Comment: Is there a logic that governs which elements should get the `Id` element? Why `Organization` but not `Bobbers`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k It could have the ```Id``` element, I omitted it from the code above since I don't need that information.  So I suppose any child element/node should inherit that id as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try along the lines of

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[*[not(*)] and ancestor::*[Id]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::*[Id]/Id | *"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  Unfortunately I can't get any info using this.  For the sample record I can pull in information via ```<Id><xsl:value-of select="../../../../../../../Id"/></Id>``` but since the ```Id``` element isn't always in the same place, for some records the ```Id``` is blank.

Comment: It is not clear why the suggestion doesn't work, it does for me at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVab. I suppose you are back to your previous namespace problem, perhaps, but you it is not possible to tell.

Comment: I don't think it's a namespace problem since I've removed reference to it for testing. I've taken some production data and using your XSLT I can replicate the ```Id``` element everywhere I need, so thanks for that.  I think MS Access may be the culprit...Using the same XML and XSLT during the transformation no ```Id``` element appears in the ```Add``` block.

Comment: At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbspVab/1 I have used MSXML 6 instead of XslCompiledTransform. I would say MS Access uses a version of MSXML to run XSLT, can't tell which one, but it seems to work with MSXML 6 which is available on all supported Windows OS versions. I don't know whether or how you can get Access to use MSXML 6 but I really don't see any reason why MSXML 3 or 5 would fail.

Comment: Update: This does in fact work for all nodes...I found there was another node with a different name that preceded the ```Bobbers``` node that also had an ```Add``` node. For some reason when I created a blank template for this other node ala ```<xsl:template match="ExtraNode"></xsl:template>``` the ```Id``` element appeared in the ```Add``` block.